# How to fix "Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined at vuetemplatetest.2.html:19"

Tags: laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I try to setup laravel with bootstrap-vue.

```
npm list --depth 0
/home/<thatsme>/LARAPP/laravel
├── axios@0.18.0
├── bootstrap@4.3.1
├── bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.16
├── cross-env@5.2.0
├── jquery@3.3.1
├── laravel-mix@4.0.15
├── lodash@4.17.11
├── popper.js@1.14.7
├── resolve-url-loader@2.3.2
├── sass@1.17.3
├── sass-loader@7.1.0
├── vue@2.6.10
├── vue-router@3.0.2
└── vue-template-compiler@2.6.10
```

shows me, that is okay. The intention is to work without the online links.
When i try a test with simple html, i got the error described in topic theme:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <title>eijo</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<div id='app'>  
  <b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields"> </b-table>
</div>


<script>
window.app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
  data: {    fields: ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age'], 
             items: [
        { isActive: true, age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
        { isActive: false, age: 21, first_name: 'Walter', last_name: 'Shaw' },
        { isActive: false, age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
        { isActive: true, age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
      ]
  }
  }
```

Edit: in mit app.js is that:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)

// app.js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edit:]
Saved the problem:

div **id="app"** class="container"

that was missing in my layout.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

Add `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>` at top to your script.

Comment: like i wrote here: "The intention is to work without the online links". I thougt, it could be possible, to deploy an app without that? With your suggestion, it works. I knew that, but sry. Was not a good asking maybe.

Comment: Yes, but somehow you must provide the vue module. I use Vue CLI, it mount a server who does all the job. Later i can build my app and put it inside the server i want for serve the app. For example i use loopback in the back.

Comment: how does that work with vue-cli? could you explain that please? I am absolutely new in the world of node.js and npm and laravel/vue/bootstrap

Comment: In your command prompt type "npm install -g @vue/cli".
This installs vue-cli. Later type "vue ui", this open a GUI in your browser where you can create and managing your project.

This is the web page 
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

There is a lot of tutorials in youtube and websites with info. Is very easy to start.

Comment: Thx a lot Eduardo

Comment: The front end and backend are separated projects as i know, but they are related.

Comment: This actually works...but I don't think it should be the ultimate solution